# How do you refresh maven dependencies from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

We recently started using maven for dependency management. Our team uses eclipse as it's IDE. Is there an easy way to get eclipse to refresh the maven dependencies without running mvn eclipse:eclipse?

The dependencies are up to date in the local maven repository, but eclipse doesn't pick up the changes until we use the eclipse:eclipse command. This regenerates a lot of eclipse configuration files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried using the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/) plugin?  I use it with eclipse and it maintains the eclipse .classpath when I add dependencies.  It'll also check for updated dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

You generate the special eclipse files with `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, but once you've done that, you should let a [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) handle the dependencies while inside eclipse.

That's how we do it at my work place, and it generally works well.